# Navigation bar links are not clickable on website

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

The links on my site are not clickable.. I built another site earlier this year and made it work how I wanted, so I just copied that code.

```
<div id="links">
      <div class="wrap">
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="#atlanta1"; class="down link" id="space">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#atlanta2"; class="down link" id="space">FRESHMAN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#atlanta3"; class="down link" id="space">SOPHOMORE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#atlanta4"; class="down link" id="space">JUNIOR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#stoneMountain"; class="down link">SENIOR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        // Document ready shorthand statement
            $(function() {
                $('.link').click(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, 'slow');
            // Prevent default behavior of link
                    return false;
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="atlanta1">
    </div>
    <div id="atlanta2">
    </div>
    <div id="atlanta3">
    </div>
    <div id="atlanta4">
    </div>
    <div id="stoneMountain">
    </div>
```

I have blank divs just because I have them there at specific heights so the links will take me to different heights on the page. This is how I set up the style, for the links and for the divs

```
<style>

        #links {background-color: black;
             background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
            color: white;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        z-index:0}
        #navigation {list-style: none; padding: 1; margin: 18px 0px ; color: white; text-align: center;}
        #navigation li {display: inline;}
        #navigation li #space {margin-right:150px;}
        #navigation a {color: inherit; text-decoration: inherit;}

        #header, #footer {width:100%; float:left;}

        #navigation li + li {
            background:url('seperator.gif') no-repeat top left;
            padding-left: 10px
        }
        .wrap {position:relative; margin:0 auto; width:100%;}

        #atlanta1 {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            height: 1000px;
            z-index: -0
        }
        #atlanta2 {
            position:absolute;
            top:1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            z-index: -0
        }
        #atlanta3 {
            position:absolute;
            top:2000px;
            height: 1000px;
            z-index: -0
        }
        #atlanta4 {
            position:absolute;
            top:3000px;
            height: 1000px;
            z-index: -0
        }
        #stoneMountain {
            position:absolute;
            top:4000px;
            height: 1000px;
            z-index: -0
        }
    </style>
```

I've been stuck here for a while and don't really see whats wrong, but the links aren't clickable.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, but for some reason it's not. Could something wrong somewhere else cause it not to? Everything else works fine though.

Comment: What do you mean not clickable, they aren't pointing to links though.

Comment: The links in the list. Its an anchor on the same page.

Comment: So that should take you to the place on the page it is pointing towards... is that what it is doing? Clicking on these links shows that they are working http://jsfiddle.net/Sk2mY/

Comment: @user2803662 Take a look at my answer I just updated, I think I know what your talking about now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not working. Should I just show the rest of the code? How could I?

Comment: Can you give the Live link? I think you might missed something.

Comment: @SurjithSM I fixed it, look at my answer below... and a ton of comments fixing the whole dam site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by the links are not clickable.

I mean your `divs` have no width for a start so its there is no `divs` for the Javascript to scroll to. I gave them a width and seems to work ok....

**Example of giving a width:**

```
#atlanta1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100px; // Width!
    z-index: -0;
}
```

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsbin.com/EHocEji/1/edit)

As you can see the links are clickable and work.

**Note:** *I only gave a width to a few.*

---

I think I know what your talking about now, I think its because you are using `z-index`. Some of the divs are going above the header. You could try something like.

```
z-index:9999;
```

Put that in the header or as you have called it `#links`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Ddzt4/)

---

Fully working version:

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Ddzt4/3/)

---

Another update:

Right its because of this:

```
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1000px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-2;
}
```

See how you are pushing the list behind the header. Set it to 9 or something and it will comeback to the front. You may want to look up what `z-index` does.

```
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1000px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:9;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J6Tvb/5/)

Comment: I added width and it's still not working. Can/should I just show the code for the entire site?

Comment: @user2803662 I don't think its necessary for the whole site code. This is the right code. Try the second bit I said.

Comment: @user2803662 Look at my final version. Its all working there.

Comment: @user2803662 You can see in that example I made it is fully 100% working.

Comment: I know, which is why I believe the problem may be somewhere else on the site.

Comment: If the site inst big and messy code then create a JSFiddle or something. Then link me.

Comment: I don't believe it's messy, but that could just be my opinion. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jp3isme/J6Tvb/

Comment: Now the header is completely covered by the background images in the list.

Comment: if the background images won't load you won't be able to see, but if they do you can see they cover the header and you cant get to it. http://jsfiddle.net/jp3isme/J6Tvb/9/

Comment: Jesus C! You are never happy are you. I said look up about `z-index`. Just put `#links` `z-index` higher then the `ul li` I may aswell just make the site for you.[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J6Tvb/10/) No idea why you have `z-index` everywhere. But as you do go look up what it does and where to use it. Then you can fix everything else.

Comment: [**Tidy Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/J6Tvb/11/) There you go, I had a quick run through and did a little tidying for the `z-index`. Enjoy. Now at the very least you can accept the answer.

Comment: I know what z-index is. You just said though to change the z-index of ul li to 9, so it would be in front of the header: "See how you are pushing the list behind the header. Set it to 9 or something and it will comeback to the front.". So then it was covered. I went back and changed the header to be back in front, and that works, so thank you, but now its back to how it was. Header in front of list. 
Could you please just explain to me why it's different now and working?

Comment: Just look at my last comment, fully working and tidied up. You has `z-index` everywhere. There was no need for it. You got confused with what should be wear. About there was no real need to have it everywhere. Run through the tidy version and see where it was needed etc.

Comment: The reason I had it other places originally was not random. #link 4 was going to slide either over or under #link 3, and #link 3 the same for #link 2, and so on. So it wasn't random, i just never got to that part. You never did answer my question though. In the original the header was infront of everything, as it is now. So why does it work now and not then?

Comment: @user2803662 Because you was pushing `ul li` behind so the links wouldn't work. On my one `#links` is `z-index: 1;` and `ul li` doesn't have `z-index` because it doesn't need it when its sitting on `#links`. So overall you could just get rid of `z-index` on the `ul li` but all the other stuff would still be broke.

Comment: That didn't really answer what I was asking. I just don't understand because it's still in the same stack order that it was, but now its working and then it wasn't. I have a working version that I got to on my own without removing the other z-indexes because I may still need them, but yours works too so I'll give you the answer. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @user2803662 That's just it you really don't need them not at all. As you can see I got it working without using them but on 1 thing. You rarely need to use them. I only use them when its the only way to do something. For what you have created I wouldn't have used a single one if I was creating it as I see no reason why I would. Also I don't understand how I didn't explain it.

Comment: I said earlier why I may need them for later. Not right this second, but later. So link 3 would be able to go in front of or behind link 2 when scrolled up and they reach the top and stop. This isn't added yet but I was considering it.

Comment: @user2803662 Ok well I suggest having a play with `z-index` some more as I don't think you fully understand it. Just set-up a fiddle and mess around with different layouts using `z-index` I'm sure you will work out what I was saying.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. You'r right. Right now I do not need them. I have them in there because I had ideas for using them later, for a different animation. I know what z-index does, but thank you.